# What does $g_x^{-1}$ mean where $g$ is a Riemannian metric?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, optimal-transportation

I am reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2112.11056.pdf) about the Wasserstein-Fisher-Rao distance and they define the Wasserstein-Fisher-Rao distance on a manifold as follows (page 9):

Here, $M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold, $\mathcal{M}_+(M)$ is the set of positive finite Radon measures on $M$, and $\mathcal{M}(M)$ is the set of signed Radon measures on $M$.

> **Definition 7.** (Dynamical formulation of WFR metric). Let $\rho_0,\rho_1\in \mathcal{M}_+(M)$, the WFR metric is defined by $\begin{equation}\textrm{WFR}^2(\rho_0,\rho_1) = \inf_{\rho,m,\mu}\mathcal{J}(\rho,m,\mu) \tag*{} \end{equation} $ where $\begin{equation} \mathcal{J}(\rho,m,\mu) \\= \displaystyle a^2 \int_{0}^{1}\int_{M} \frac{g_x^{-1}(\tilde{m}(t,x), \tilde{m}(t,x))}{\tilde{\rho}(t,x)}d\nu(t,x) + b^2 \int_{0}^{1}\int_{M} \frac{\tilde{\mu}(t,x)^2}{\tilde{\rho}(t,x)}d\nu(t,x) \tag*{} \end{equation}$ over the set $(\rho, m, \mu)$ satisfying $\rho\in \mathcal{M}_+([0,1]\times M), m\in (\Gamma_M^{0}([0,1]\times M, TM))^*$ which denotes the dual of time dependent continuous vector fields on $M$ (time dependent sections of the tangent bundle, $\mu\in \mathcal{M}([0,1]\times M)$... Moreover, $\nu$ is chosen such that $\rho,m,\mu$ are absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$ and $\tilde{\rho},\tilde{m},\tilde{\mu}$ denote their Radon-Nikodym derivative with respect to $\nu$.

My question is: what is $g_x^{-1}$ here? It should not be a reciprocal of the Riemannian metric because that goes against the definition of WFR in the Euclidean setting.

I am also confused about what "Radon-Nikodym derivative" means for $m$, since it is not really a measure. My guess is as follows:

---

In geometric measure theory, the duals of $k$-forms are called $k$-currents, and since $1$-forms can be identified as vector fields through Riemannian metric, the dual space of smooth vector fields can be seen as the space of 1-currents. A 1-current (with good enough condition) can be represented by an integral (copied from Geometric Measure Theory, A Beginner's Guide by Frank Morgan):

$\displaystyle T(\phi) = \int \langle \vec{T}(x),\phi(x)\rangle d\|T\| \tag*{}$

where $\langle,\rangle$ is an inner product (the book only talks about the Euclidean case, but the above has obvious generalization in the case of Riemannian manifold), $\vec{T}$ is a vector field such that $(\vec{T},\vec{T})=1$, and $\| T\| $ is a Radon measure. This theorem can be seen as a decomposition theorem of a current into a "vector part" $\vec{T}$ and a "measure" part $\|T\|$, and using this decomposition, we can define the Radon Nikodym derivative of $T$, a 1-current on $M$, by $\nu\in \mathcal{M}_+(M)$, as

$\displaystyle \frac{dT}{d\nu} = \vec{T} \frac{d\|T\|}{d\nu}\tag*{}$

which is well-defined since $\|T\|$ is a genuine measure.

---

The above is a guess, so I don't know if it is a good definition. I thought maybe it is a dual metric defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3406997/inverse-metric-on-riemannian-manifold), but it does not make sense if I took my definition of Radon-Nikodym, since $\frac{dT}{d\nu}$ is an element of $TM$ and not $T^*M$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor#Inverse_metric